# Помогите разобрать код на Си

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void CntTo3(int);
void CntTo2(int);
void CntTo1(int);
int main() {
    int n;
    CntTo3(3);
    return 0;
}
void CntTo3(int p) {
    CntTo2(p-1);
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
void CntTo2(int p) {
    CntTo1(p-1);
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
void CntTo1(int p) {
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
```

После компиляции, показывается ответ как -

```
1
2
3
```

Получается, чтобы вывести 1 в функции `CntTo3`, нужно выполнить функцию `CntTo2`, которая будет равняться 2, ну и `CntTo1` уже выводит без вычислений 3. Я правильно понял? Если да, то почему в `main()` определяется `CntTo3(3)` и зачем переменная `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main() {
    int n;
    CntTo3(3);
    return 0;
}
void CntTo3(int p) {
    CntTo2(p-1);
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
void CntTo2(int p) {
    CntTo1(p-1);
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
void CntTo1(int p) {
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
```

Давайте просто подставлять код вместо вызова:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    CntTo2(2);
    printf("%d\n",3);
    return 0;
}
void CntTo2(int p) {
    CntTo1(p-1);
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
void CntTo1(int p) {
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
```

Следующая подстановка:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    CntTo1(1);
    printf("%d\n",2);
    printf("%d\n",3);
    return 0;
}
void CntTo1(int p) {
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
```

И последняя:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    printf("%d\n",1);
    printf("%d\n",2);
    printf("%d\n",3);
    return 0;
}
```

Так понятнее?

Переменная `n` нигде не работает (кстати, компилятор должен предупредить об этом).

Comment: `void CntTo3(int);
void CntTo2(int);
void CntTo1(int);`
То есть этот код вызывает функции до main() и определяет порядок вызова?

Comment: Этот код просто ОБЪЯВЛЯЕТ, что есть такие функции с такими именами. Вы можете перенести на место объявления определения (с телами функций, идущие после `main()`), - и все будет работать. Просто объявления нужны компилятору, чтоб он знал, что такая функция вообще-то есть. А последовательность вызовов определена в `main()`. Вызывается `CntTo3` - так что *вместо вызова* я могу просто записать ее код, что она делает - а это вызов `CntTo2` и вывод тройки. И так далее..

Comment: Все понял, Большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Тут такая ситуация: вызов функции и печать на экран, играет большую роль.
Если поменять местами вызова функции и вывода на экран, получится 3,2,1

Тут главное порядок.

Сначала выполняется вызов другой функции, а потом уже вывод текущего значения.
Если поменять местами:

```
void CntTo3(int p) {
    printf("%d\n",p);
    CntTo2(p-1);
}
void CntTo2(int p) {
    printf("%d\n",p);
    CntTo1(p-1);
}
void CntTo1(int p) {
    printf("%d\n",p);
}
```

тогда получится 3,2,1

и это не рекурсия. Рекурсия это тогда, когда функция вызывает сама себя

```
void CntTo3(int p) {
    if (p>1)
       CntTo3(p-1);
    printf("%d\n",p);        
}
```

попробуйте так тоже.